# Elegant way to format a WPF datagrid populated from SQL

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I built a very generic `DataGrid` that is bound to a generic `DataTable` which is fed by some SQL result.  The columns of output vary depending on the request.  While I can go into the query itself and do the formatting there, and be frowned at for not doing the formatting at the UI level, I am still not sure what elegant way to do the formatting would be.

My DataGrid is

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"
 AutoGenerateColumns="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dgSummary" >
</DataGrid>
```

Then my code behind is like this:

```
DataTable dtSummary=new DataTable();
SQLstr = "select * from MyData";
dtSummary = GetSummary(cnn, SQLstr);
this.dgSummary.ItemsSource = dtSummary.AsDataView();
```

GetSummary is just the service call returning the results in as a datatable.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: What kind of formatting do you mean? Could you explain a bit more, what you want to archieve?

Comment: I don't really understand the question... Are you doubting the approach to use a DataTable as the grid's ItemsSource, because a datatable inherently has a formatting in distinction to using 'raw' data, i.e. a list of some objects?

Comment: Sorry.  Some of the data is going to be standard numbers, so I would like to do ###,###. type of format.  Other fields will be percents, so I would like to do something like #.##%.

Comment: As of now, I am leaning toward defining my columns individually for the datatable. But I would still love to know if there is a nice way to format the numeric fields based on the above, where the columns are based on the SQL query data returned.

The reason I am moving away from the above is because I want flexibility in naming my column headers as well as the numeric formats of a column.  

Thus, if the SQL query is like "Select Year1, Year1 Sales from xxx" I want to have my datagrid show what Year1 was, like "2013" and also be able to format Year1 Sales as "#,###.00".